# WCF XML serialization and excluding datetime tags where value is DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

I am consuming large business objects from a third party. These objects are provided via WSDL and xsd files so I can not change the object as these are to be returned via a WCF service call.

Given that I can't change the objects I can't annotate the properties with the [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute or directly control the serialization of these objects.

The problem I am trying to resolve is this. If a datetime objects within one of the business objects has a value of DateTime.MinValue is it possible it excluded that piece of data from the XML serialization without implementing a completely bespoke serialization implementation? If there a way to tell the default XML serializer to ignore an object based on its value?

**Example of part of the large business object from the Reference.cs**

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://XXXX")]
public partial class DocumentBusinessProperty : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string documentBusinessPropertyNameField;

    private string[] documentBusinessPropertyValueField;

    private System.DateTime documentBusinessPropertyDateField;

    private bool documentBusinessPropertyDateFieldSpecified;

    private bool documentBusinessPropertyIndicatorField;

    private bool documentBusinessPropertyIndicatorFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string DocumentBusinessPropertyName {
        get {
            return this.documentBusinessPropertyNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.documentBusinessPropertyNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentBusinessPropertyName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DocumentBusinessPropertyValue", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string[] DocumentBusinessPropertyValue {
        get {
            return this.documentBusinessPropertyValueField;
        }
        set {
            this.documentBusinessPropertyValueField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentBusinessPropertyValue");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date", Order=2)]
    public System.DateTime DocumentBusinessPropertyDate {
        get {
            return this.documentBusinessPropertyDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.documentBusinessPropertyDateField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentBusinessPropertyDate");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DocumentBusinessPropertyDateSpecified {
        get {
            return this.documentBusinessPropertyDateFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.documentBusinessPropertyDateFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentBusinessPropertyDateSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    public bool DocumentBusinessPropertyIndicator {
        get {
            return this.documentBusinessPropertyIndicatorField;
        }
        set {
            this.documentBusinessPropertyIndicatorField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentBusinessPropertyIndicator");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DocumentBusinessPropertyIndicatorSpecified {
        get {
            return this.documentBusinessPropertyIndicatorFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.documentBusinessPropertyIndicatorFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DocumentBusinessPropertyIndicatorSpecified");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```